# unexpected > T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or > T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}'

Tags: php, error-handling

Anything stand out on line 37 or perhaps the way this class constructor is made?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or
>   T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in
>   /dir/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/test/category-images/category-images.php
>   on line 37

```
class CategoryImagesII extends CategoryImagesII_Plugin
{

protected $error_codes = array(); // LINE 37
protected $error_strings = array();
```

Comment: No, but parse errors like this very often are misreported.  What I mean is, your actual bug or typo is somewhere else, this is just the line where the parser trips up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet it's PHP 4 acting up, because it does not recognize the PHP 5-only `protected` keyword.

Comment: Bingo. Can you suggest a backwards compatible option for that?

Comment: @Scott B: Use `var` instead, but your properties will be public.

Comment: meaning that there's a possibility for scope issues or variable clashes?

Comment: @Scott B: Nope, just a possibility that outside code will see or modify your properties.